# regex_error being thrown when trying to do simple things like [:digit:] or \d

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, codeblocks, gnu

Every time I put `[:digit:]` in a regex like so: `regex r("[:digit:]")` it throws an exception and `.what()` just returns `regex_error` instead of a descriptive, meaningful explanation of the error. Same things happens when I try `regex r("\\d")`. And when I try `regex r("\d")` my compiler says that `\d` is an unfamiliar character escape sequence. I'm in Code::Blocks by the way. Here's my code:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   regex r("\d"); //and or r("[:digit:]")
   string i = "5";
   if(regex_match(i,r))
       {
           cout << "Integer";
       }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using gcc: last time I checked gcc has not yet implemented full support for std::regex. This may or may not have changed with the current version of gcc. Check gcc's documentation for more information.

Comment: If you are matching for a digit use **[0-9]*** I don't think your version of C++ is POSIX compliant.

Comment: Just corrected my code Jonny Henly. Thanks.

Comment: Just uninstalled the old Code::Blocks and am installing v16.01. I had v13.12! xD Thanks guys! :)

Comment: You need to use GCC 4.8.2 or 4.9 (I forget which one) but 4.9+ has regex support.

Comment: Yeah, after installing the new version of Code::Blocks and implementing the compiler setting `-std=c++11` it worked. And downloading MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a newer version of Code::Blocks and the MinGW GCC compiler suite it worked.

P.S. I kept having an error when trying to set the compiler after downloading Code::Blocks. I had to go to `Global compiler settings` and click `Reset defaults` for it to auto-detect my compiler. As seen [here](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17336.0#msg_118963_quick_mod).